# Eclipse - pyqt application opening in a separate window in MAC

Tags: eclipse, pyqt, pydev

I have a very simple pyqt application and using Eclipse pydev to develop my application.

```python
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try to run this application, it opens a pyqt application as a separate window and I have to do a Ctrl + TAB to find the application.

Is there a way for eclipse pydev to open the small app within eclipse window itself.

Comment: Seems unlikely. Eclipse uses the SWT GUI which on macOS interfaces directly to the Cocoa UI code.

Comment: No, it's not possible to open a window from your application inside Eclipse itself (so, you really need to manually focus the other window... you can probably make it the active window through the PyQt API thought, but I don't have the solution offhand).